# Multiple dependent selects in Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to get a series of dependent selects working in Knockout JS.  I can get one working following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893276/dependent-select-knockout) thread, but I'm struggling to get more than one operational.

The idea is to have subjects and levels and allow a user to select one subject and one (or more) levels at a time.

For example:

User selects "Math" in the primary select.  The dependent select then changes options to "Calculus,Algebra,Geometry".  User selects two of the three.

Simple enough so far.

Then the user wants to select an additional pair of subjects and levels.  So clicks on a button that adds another row of primary and dependent select elements.  The user selects "English" and the dependent select changes options to "Language,Literature,History" so they can select from those too.

Now there are two rows of selects.  One with subject Math and the other with subject English.

I've tried to get this working on a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lifeform/45myn8eb/) but for reasons I'm not entirely sure about the thing won't even load.

```
self.subjLevList = ko.observableArray([
    {subject: "Math", levels: ["Calculus", "Algebra"]},
    {subject: "English", levels: ["Language", "Literature"]} ]);
```

I've been staring at this for so long I've probably missed some obvious stuff, but if someone can help me that would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixing the reference errors

> for reasons I'm not entirely sure about the thing won't even load

Your browser's developer tools are your friend. If your views won't render, knockout usually provides a handy error message in console. In your case, the first one's this:

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding `foreach: function (){return subjLevVM.subjLevList }`*
>   *Message: `subjLevVM` is not defined*

This means there's something wrong in your binding context: there's no property named `subjLevVM`, so  there's no way to access the array `subjLevList`.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcc258um/) with all reference errors fixed. If you find it difficult to find these, have a look at [this answer I wrote earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45615949/3297291).

### Implementing the described behavior

The behavior you're aiming for isn't easy to create. I started an implementation in your current fiddle, but had to change so much that it didn't get any clearer...

Eventually, I re-implemented the structure in a series of `Rows`, `Labs` and `options`.

- You can only add rows if there are still `Labs` not in use
- When changing a Row's lab, you can only pick from the ones not in use

Each layer uses `computed` properties to limit options. If any part of the code is unclear or otherwise hard to follow, please let me know and I'll be happy to further clarify.

```js
var Lab = function(name, id, options, labsInUse) {
  this.name = name;
  this.id = id;
  
  this.options = options;
  this.selectedOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  this.disabled = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return labsInUse().some(function(thatId) {
      return thatId === id;
    });
  });
};

Lab.fromData = function(d, idsInUse) {
  return new Lab(d.lab_name, d.id, d.lab_options.split(","), idsInUse);
}

var Row = function(labs) {
  this.labs = labs;
  
  this.selectedLab = ko.observable(labs.find(function(l) {
      return !l.disabled();
    })
  );
  
  this.setOptionDisable = function(option, item) {
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, { disable: item.disabled }, item);
  }
};

var App = function(courseData, initialSelection) {

  this.rows = ko.observableArray([]);

  // Every lab can only be added once
  var labIdsInUse = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.rows().map(function(r) {
      return r.selectedLab() && r.selectedLab().id;
    });
  }, this);
  
  var labs = courseData.map(function(d) {
    return Lab.fromData(d, labIdsInUse)
  });
  
  // Display a report of selections
  this.selection = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.rows()
      .map(function(r) {
        var lab = r.selectedLab();
        return lab.name + ", with subjects: " + lab.selectedOptions().join(", ");
      });
  }, this);
  
  this.canAdd = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return labs.length > labIdsInUse().length;
  }, this);
  
  this.addRow = function() {
    this.rows.push(new Row(labs));
  }.bind(this);
  
  this.removeRow = function(row) {
    this.rows.remove(row);
  }.bind(this);
  
  // Set initial selection
  Object.keys(initialSelection)
    .map(function(labName) {
      var row = new Row(labs);
      var labToSelect = labs.find(function(lab) {
        return lab.name === labName;
      });
      
      // Set options
      labToSelect.selectedOptions(
        initialSelection[labName]
      );
      
      // Add lab to row
      row.selectedLab(labToSelect);
      
      // Add row to app
      this.rows.push(row);
      
    }.bind(this));
};

ko.applyBindings(
  new App(
    getCourseData(),
    {"Math": ["Calculus", "Algebra"], "English": ["Language"]}  
  )
);


function getCourseData(){return[{id:"1003",lab_name:"Math",lab_index:"1",lab_options:"Calculus,Algebra,Geometry"},{id:"1004",lab_name:"English",lab_index:"2",lab_options:"Language,Literature,History"},{id:"1005",lab_name:"History",lab_index:"3",lab_options:"Ancient,Modern"}]}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: rows">
  <div>
    <select data-bind="options: labs, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedLab, optionsAfterRender: setOptionDisable"></select>
    <!-- ko with: selectedLab -->
    <select data-bind="options: options, selectedOptions: selectedOptions" multiple></select> 
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeRow">delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: addRow, enable: canAdd">add lab</button>

<h3>Selection:</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: selection">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, really nice solution - thank you so much!  Thank you also for the fiddle fixing the reference errors.  Once I saw your fix, it all became clear.  I'd become bogged down and couldn't see straight.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how to set the initial state of the selects.  Say we started with something like this ```{"Math": ["Calculus", "Algebra"], "English": ["Language"]}``` How would you load the rows observableArray?

Comment: I've added the option to pass an initial selection to the example. We first create *all* labs from the course data. Then, we find the lab corresponding to the selection using `find` comparing names. Once we have the `lab` we're looking for, we add the options and inject a row.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you again for your assistance!